# what If I leave France without closing my account of french bank?

Tags: france

I've been in FRANCE almost 1 year(from 2011 to 2012).

The problem is that when I came back to my country, I didn't close my bank account.

As people know, French bank have bank charges for storage, and I'm really afraid of cumulative effect of charges for 5 years....

So what I wanna ask you is :

1. Does french bank accounts have self-closing system?
2. Because of my bank account, would I have disadvantage in any way when I go back to france again?

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Have you tried calling your bank there? Just last week I phoned Canada to close a bank account I used to have there.

Comment: I don't understand your second question, but if you want to close your bank account, you'll probably have to send a mail, "courrier recommande". You can do it remotely with this website: https://boutique.laposte.fr/envoi-de-courrier-en-ligne/lettre-recommandee-en-ligne

Comment: I don't really know--you'd have to ask your bank to be sure. But in the past  I've abandoned a checking account without paying the fees (there were only a few dollars left in the account) and after a time the bank simply closed the account.  So I doubt any authorities are going to come after you for unpaid bank fees if you return to France.